# How do I tell what index a letter is in a string? (In Python, JS, Ruby, PHP etc...)

Tags: javascript, python

I know that:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print alphabet[0]
# prints a
print alphabet[25]
#prints z
```

and so on, but how do I find out the opposite, ie. :

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
's' = alphabet[?]
""" The question mark represents that I want to know 
what index the letter is in the string."""
```

Comment: There are as many answers as there are languages out there, are there not?

Comment: Please pick a language!

Answer (score 2):

In python you could use the find method:

```
>>> alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
>>> alphabet.find('a')
0
>>> alphabet.find('b')
1
>>> alphabet.find('c')
>>> alphabet.find('z')
25
```

Edit to add: Like Warren pointed out you can also use `index`, the difference being that `find` will return `-1` for the position if not found, and `index` raises a `ValueError` when not found.

In javascript, use `indexOf`:

```
> "abc".indexOf("b")
1
```

Comment: Or `alphabet.index('c')`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you would use `alphabet.indexOf('a')`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, to get the position of a certain character inside a string, it would be:

```
alphabet.index('s')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get alphabet indices, this works (Python):

```
import string
for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print(ord(c)-97)
```

This will print the numbers 0-25. The idea here is to make use of unicode points of the char using [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord). lowercase chars starts at 97. Another example:

```
>>> ord('k')-97
10
```